# How to load second audio layer from avi file in camtasia studio?

Tags: camtasia

I have AVI file with 2 audio layers: one is Russian and second one is original English track. When I play this video in, for example, kmplayer video is starting to play with Russian track, when I press ctrl+x I switch audio layers and get original English speech. I want to edit this video file with camtasia studio but when I add it to timeline I get video and only one Russian speech track without original English speech. I tried to turn on additional audio/sound timelines but there are no additional audio layers displayed for this file. How can I edit this AVI format file and get English audio layer in camtasia studio???